# Location of class files for tomcat

Tags: android

I am trying to connect to the server from android through tomcat server. There is a .class file which should be eecuted. I have placed this in C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/LoginServlet.java

to access this from android, I have given the statement,

```
response = SimpleHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/webapps/examples/WEB-       INF/classes/LoginServlet", postParameters);
```

Is that corrext? Do I have to place it in a different location or change the path above ?

Comment: where do you call `galleryAddPic()`. Looks like you don't call it anywhere

Comment: I don't know where exactly to call it. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: i don't know either with what you have posted its not clear

Comment: Will it work if I call it in the method where I'm creating the intent for the camera ?

Comment: yes it should work if you call it in a method